# take the number parameter been passed and return the factorial of it, For example: if number is 4, it should return (4 * 3 * 2 * 1) which is 24

Tags: javascript

Have a function factorial(number), take the number parameter been passed and return the factorial of it.

For example: if number is 4, it should return (4 * 3 * 2 * 1) which is 24

Comment: see how you can use a loop or a recursive function

Comment: Google it! You will find the complete code!

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript%20factorial%20of%20a%20number

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how to ask here

Answer (score 1):

```js
function factorial(number) {
    return (number <= 1) ? 1 : factorial(number - 1) * number;
}

alert(factorial(4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```js
    function factorial(f,n) {
      var l=1;
      for(i=1;i<=n;i++) l=l*i;
      f.p.value=l;
    }
```

```html
    <form>
    number:<input type="text" name="t"></br>
    <input type="button" value="Run" onClick="factorial(this.form,t.value)"></br>
    result:<input type="text" name="p"></br>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways to go about this: recursively and iteratively.

The recursive way is to write a function that calls itself until a given condition is answered. It's easier to code and conceptualize, but it's slower and eats more memory.

```
function factorial(n) {
    if (n < 0) throw "Negative factorial undefined";
    return (n <= 1) ? 1 : factorial(n-1)*n;
}
```

The iterative version looks more cumbersome, but in most cases it's faster and less memory intensive:

```
function factorialIterative(n) {
    if (n < 0) throw "Negative factorial undefined";
    var fact = 1;
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        fact *= i;
    }
    return fact;
}
```

You can see the difference in performance of the recursive vs the iterative solutions at [this jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/recursive-vs-iterative-factorial).

*Note*: These versions also do parameter checking (which you should make sure to do to avoid weird bugs) and include the n=0 edge-case